# Website is not running when point on the server?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have setup my website on the server. I configured the database with the website.

When I hit the website URL in the browser, it shows error "page isn't working"

But when I hit the test file from the root, it is working.

What is the issue, could you please help?

Comment: You are probably missing some of the dependancies. Use n98-magerun to make sure your server supports Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you enabled web rewrites when you configured the site? If so, you'll need to rename the `htaccess.sample` file in the Magento root to `.htaccess` and possibly configure it to work with your server - but start by renaming it and refreshing your web page to see if that resolves your error.